# FreeMarker FMPP Failed to evaluate function "csv"

Tags: csv, ant, freemarker, fmpp

Using FMPP version 0.9.15, I'm following the documentation examples to pull data from a CSV file. If I use command line with config.fmpp:

```
sourceRoot: src
outputRoot: out
data: {tdd(data/style.tdd), birds:csv(data/birds.csv)}
```

Or ANT config:

```
<project name="FMPP test" default="build">

    <taskdef name="fmpp" classname="fmpp.tools.AntTask">
        <classpath>
           <pathelement location="lib/fmpp.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="build">
        <fmpp
              sourceRoot="src" outputRoot="out"
              data="tdd(data/style.tdd), birds:csv(data/birds.csv)"
        />
    </target>
</project>
```

I receive the following error either way:

```
TDD error: Failed to evaluate function "csv".
tdd(data/style.tdd), birds:csv(data/birds.csv)
                       ^
```

On the other hand, If I switch to "birds:text..." or "birds:splitText..." I do not get the evaluation error.  It looks like csv is still supported in the code. Any idea why the TDD data source is not recognizing the csv function?

Comment: Isn't there a stack trace that tells if in what way has this failed? That could help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a space  between `birds:` and `csv(data/birds.csv)`?

```
data: {
    tdd(data/style.tdd)
    birds: csv(data/birds.csv)
}
```